# Distributed Cache Breaks

Tags: service, cache, distributedcache

After enabling my Distributed Cache on my SharePoint site I received and error.

When i navigated to My distributed Cache service I noticed the service had started but wasn't "Compliant" and had a "X" with a link to "Fix"(AS in image below CMD prompt,sorry its so small). When I click the "Fix" link the page refreshes and my Distributed Cache service is then turned off. I cant start the service from in the CA so Iv'e used Shell and it starts the service fine. But the service still gets the "Fix" link, which breaks the service when clicked. Real confused on this. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Ps. Cache Host is up and running fine aswell.[image: Host is up]

[image]

Comment: What is server minrole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waqas Sarwar is pointing you in the right direction...I was seeing the same issue and after talking to MS, I had to change the role of one of my farm servers. I originally had a wfe, an app server, and a search server. I was trying to run distributed cache on the app server, but minrole doesn't see that as being in compliance because the application server role doesn't include distributed cache. The two options were to build a dedicated distributed cache server (which, I believe, incurs another sharepoint license) or change one of the server roles to custom. I went with changing the Application server to Custom. Use Central Administration to change the role - go to System Settings, Servers, Convert server role in this farm. You can use powershell Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance and Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance to straighten out dist cache once you get the minrole piece hashed out.

Comment: May I know what actually will happen after I change server role from "Front-end" to "Custom"? I can manually setup Distributed Cache with PowerShell but I am worrying what "role change" is actually doing.

Comment: Same as @Mark L, I have a server which min-role is Front-End. I read in [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016) that the perfect minrole should be Front-End with Distributed Cache, but strangely my Centrale Admin does not propose that option when changing min-role